# How to decrypt a string with unknow encryption algorithm, help me?

Tags: encryption

How to decrypt a string with unknow encryption algorithm?

There is a string:

```
AgF8ZSL8gPMgnjRt/2MQYmvTdDRxP/z0Rdt0a/2kNGhRldJcvwmShr2HtVW5nrUO8ZMqQDJhL5rpSc6xzqS7uZ42 rr9Tt5XCGMUswTKWxOlOUQ==
```

and

```
gH7PoV9ADLnysp1cLW+GJA8NfXebOkIseAUJtxaIiTD+T7eGX VXYzWw+wfFpksRWrTtMo98lm/064Zv3ZggISVzrspZpV3faC+jW82Tg3ywnrZCHihy2lub30XjH 9kT3R47gufHCPkZrBVIcaA1Nmm4uDmJLzC0FfItid2jyMiOGiW illHVBZ7HhOjFOuBlvRJwtOit801BFeqMD5kdnuon4KufDVy8N Sww0hTIxXfJmDeF/3Ks/Guu1pmj0UXnbollE5UsqqqP1HIMwdDqY/FP
```

I don't know the encryption algorithm. How to decrypt it?

To analyze and solve this problem, what should I learn?

Comment: The top string is Base64 encoded so it is necessary to decode first. The second string has 4 space characters embedded in it so it is not valid Base64 but if the space characters are removed and a "=" added to the end it will be valid Base64 and decode.

Comment: If you don't have the encryption key you will not be able to decrypt the strings, that is the point of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to have a look at the code, that would be the easiest way. I assume that is not possible so it will probably end up in educated guessing.

However, there is a large conversation about that topic here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used

First steps would probably be to find out if it is a hash or not and if it is salted. If you were able to hash/encrypt data and look at the results, try to hash/encrypt the same data twice. If the result differs, there is probably a salt used.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for help, i'm try