# How to decrypt a string with unknow encryption algorithm, heeeelp?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

How to decrypt a string with unknow encryption algorithm?

There is a 2 strings:

**2ec9e4f0-2813-4753-a0e3-21bfcb3d5832**

**e349f2cf-0e01-4fcf-b100-78727c69286e**

I don't know the encryption algorithm. How to decrypt it?

To analyze and solve this problem, what should I learn?

Comment: Where did you get these strings from? Why do you need to decrypt them? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The whole point in encryption is to stop you from doing this without the correct key.

Comment: Using a different account you posted almost the same exact question (with the same semi-literate typos) previously: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35887467/4996248 Don't do that. It is highly annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is an identifier standard used
>   in software construction. A UUID is simply a 128-bit value. The
>   meaning of each bit is defined by any of several variants.
>
> For human-readable display, many systems use a canonical format using
>   hexadecimal text with inserted hyphen characters. For example:
>   **123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000**

This is not an encrypted string, it's just [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Point for you - you've beaten me by seconds ([GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier))... +1

Comment: so, what is the string behind this unique identifier ?

Comment: There is no string behind, UUID does not have any meaning, it's only purpose is to be unique.

Comment: so there is no relation between the 2 uuid in my question ?

Comment: They can be related inside the application, but basically each UUID it's just random string, you can't extract any information from it.